# Como limpar um redirecionamento 301 que já foi armazenado no cache do navegador?

Tags: htaccess

Para ficar fácil entender o problema, vou chamar o site que teve o redirecionamento de "A" e o destino de "B"

Um redirecionamento 301 (ao invés de 302) foi realizado do site A para o site B sem qualquer data de expiração, visto que o servidor não estava enviando os cabeçalhos "expires", os usuários que acessaram no momento continuam sendo redirecionados para o site B, mesmo com o redirecionamento do .htaccess removido (comportamento padrão de um redirecionamento 301).

No entanto o site A é bem acessado e no tempo que ficou dessa forma, alguns usuários acessaram. Por sorte ambos os domínios são de propriedades que temos acesso, no entanto não podemos criar outro redirect (mesmo que 302) do site B para o site A, para invalidar o anterior nos navegadores que já armazenaram em cache.

Essa técnica funciona, **no entanto o site B também é muito acessado.**

**Gostaria de saber se existe algum meio de limpar esse redirecionamento nos navegadores que armazenaram em cache, sem a intervenção do usuário.**

Uma possível solução era detectar se o site B foi acessado pelo site A e gerenciar isso por algum script em PHP por exemplo (criando um redirecionamento de volta, somente quando tivesse sido de origem do site A, criando um loop que invalida o cache). No entanto não encontrei nenhuma variável que possa determinar que o site tenha sido redirecionado e sua origem tenha sido o site A.

> **Atualizado**

Recebi algumas respostas para invalidar o cache, elas funcionam, no entanto não posso deixar o domínio B redirecionando para o A para invalidar o cache, **pois ambos são sites diferentes e bem acessados.**

Existe alguma solução para esse problema?

Comment: A resposta funciona para sites diferentes, basta que o .htaccess esteja no site que será redirecionado, eu expliquei no comentário, se o seu site B foi *invadido* (eu não entendi como ele pode ter sido invadido), então você pode apontar o DNS dele para uma nova hospedagem, já que você deve ter acesso aos dados como CNAME no registo de donimio. Caso não tiver os dados então o problema não tem haver com *programação*, mas sim com algo judicial, você vai ter que entrar em contato com quem gerencia o dominio e talvez abrir um processo (não entendo de juridico), mas depende do que ocorreu...

Comment: ... Agora essa história de invadido é que esta confusa demais, se esta invadido o tal invasor pode fazer o que quiser, ou você perdeu simplesmente o acesso por outro motivo? Explica melhor isto por favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O "cache" do redirecionamento fica no cliente (navegador ou na *base de dados* buscadores), o que você tem que fazer é mover o novo endereço passe a redirecionar para o antigo novamente.

Supondo que primeiro você mova `http://site/foo.html` para `http://site/baz.html`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo\.html$ baz.html [R=301,L]
```

O navegador vai armazenar isto (e os buscadores como o Google também), então se você quiser voltar a desconsiderar o "cache" (**nota:** não tem haver com header Cache-Control) será necessário mover de volta, invertendo baz.html por foo.html, assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^baz\.html$ foo.html [R=301,L]
```

Isso vale mesmo em sites de domínios diferentes, o novo site vai precisar de um `.htaccess` ou ter em seus headers o direcionamento de volta.

Então provavelmente o *cliente* vai *revalidar*, claro que se tratando de um navegador não posso afirmar que isto ocorra em todos, se ocorre então infelizmente o jeito é limpar os dados de navegação.

Comment: Já imaginei um IE antigo recebendo o 301, aí indo para o endereço cached, pegando o 301 e indo pro outro endereço, e assim sucessivamente até fritar o computador ou o cache ficar inválido

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado vou efetuar o teste, tenho um XP em um netbook antigo aqui :)

Comment: Eu testei no Windows 7, não me lembro qual a versão do IE, no entanto funcionou. Funciona com um redirect 302 também, o problema é que o domínio que foi redirecionado (destino), também é utilizado, logo não posso deixar ele "fora do ar".

Comment: Um comentário a fora do meu problema atual, imaginem se um site é invadido e redirecionado para outro que o administrador não tem acesso? Game Over? É uma questão um tanto quanto problemática, principalmente quando o público principal desse site é mais leigo.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri como assim *"invadido"*? Você tem acesso ao registro de dominio (não tem nada haver com hospedagem), vocÊ pode mudar o dns (tipo se for um dominio com `.com.br` vá em https://registro.br) para apontar para uma nova hospedagem, uma hospedagem pode ter vários dominios, você pode resolver tudo na sua hospedagem atual, desde que ambos dominios apontem para o mesmo DNS. Então no rewritecond vc verifica o dominio.